# SQL returns result with 0 rows

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

```
    function getData()
    {
        $select_query = "SELECT Value FROM Allies WHERE 'Key'='14638'";

        mysqli_real_escape_string($this -> dataConnection, $this -> cacheKey);
        mysqli_real_escape_string($this -> dataConnection, $this -> id);

        if ($result = $this -> dataConnection ->query($select_query)) {
            printf("Select returned %d rows.\n", $result->num_rows);

            /* free result set */
            $result->close();
        }

    }
```

For some reason, this code prints "Select returned 0 rows" when the data exists and nothing when the data doesn't exist.

Here's a screenshot of the data, if that helps:

[image]

How can I fix it and access the data?

Comment: Try to remove the single quotes around 'Key' in your query SELECT.

Comment: You're not catching the results of those `mysqli_real_escape_string`s. And it's better to use [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Key` is a reserved word. So use bacticks instead of quotes:

Change this:

```
 $select_query = "SELECT Value FROM Allies WHERE 'Key'='14638'";
```

To:

```
 $select_query = "SELECT Value FROM Allies WHERE `Key`='14638'";
```

Comment: The query stopped returning anything.

Comment: Key is a reserved word, use backticks instead.